# How can we call custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Linter gives me an error saying that I should not call a custom hook in useCallback.
How can I fix this issue?

I just want to call a custom hook that makes a POST to the Web API.

I just want to execute a Submit called from a child comport.
The custom hook needs 3 arguments.

The limitation is that the values used in the arguments are available via the Web API, so I need a little time to get them.

```js
const ParentComponent: FC = () => {

・・・・
・・・・

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    if (!param1 || !param2 || !param3) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await useCustomHookSample(
        param1,
        param2,
        param3,
      );
      setIsLoading(false);
      //do something
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      //handle error
    }
  }, [param1, param2, param3,]);

・・・・
・・・・

  return (
    <>
      <ChildrenComponent
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </>
  );


}
```

Comment: that's right, you cannot call hook inside callback, it might be better to change the way of handling your issue, please provide some more information

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). The first rule is they must be called at the top-level of your component function.

For a hook to work, in your situation you'd define it at the top:

```
const ParentComponent: FC = () => {
  const doHookCallback = await useCustomHookSample();

  const someAsyncEvent = async () => {
    const results = await doHookCallback(param1, param2, param3);
    // ...
  };
  
  //...
```

Although, this clearly would require a refactor of your hook which is incorrectly firing it's `POST` when simply instantiated. The hook should return a callback function when instantiated which then lets you run the API request when needed.

*Or just avoid the whole mess entirely* and just use `fetch` hooks via [use-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-http) or `Axios` hooks via [use-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks) (which requires [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)).